# Playing League of Legends on an external monitor with Apple silicon (display glitchiness)

Tags: macos, display, games, apple-silicon, rosetta-2

I just bought myself a 14" MacBook Pro (M1 Pro), which I use as my personal computer, including for casually playing League of Legends (a popular MOBA game).

I am connected to an external display (LG UltraFine 4K 24MD4KL-B) and some external peripherals (mouse, keyboard).

League of Legends runs via Rosetta 2 on Apple Silicon macs, and runs perfectly fine on the built-in display. I run into some issues, however, when connecting my external display: input lag, screen stutter/flaky pixels/glitchy display (I can provide a video to illustrate).

The weird thing is, disconnecting and reconnecting the thunderbolt cable once in-game solves the issue: display becomes pristine, there's no discernible input lag, everything works perfectly. However, this workaround causes the OS to malfunction post-game: application switching no longer works, and subsequent games load into a black screen. A restart solves the issue (but it means I have to restart my machine after every game).

This is kind of a frustrating issue, so I wonder if anyone has faced a similar problem or knows of a potential fix? Also, I don't know which part of the chain is to blame in this: the game itself? macOS Monterey? Rosetta 2? I want to push for an investigation, but I don't want to go barking up the wrong tree.

Full specs:

- 2021 14" MacBook Pro (M1 Pro, 16GB, 1TB)
- LG UltraFine 4K 24MD4KL-B
- External peripherals
- macOS Monterey 12.0.1 (21A559)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Sadly I have the same issue, same setup(lol) 2023. But the trick with borderless doesn't solve things for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welp, I've found the solution by myself!

For anyone who runs into this issue in the future: **you have to run the game in Borderless mode (Options > Video > Window mode).**

Game runs smooth as butter now :)

Answer (score 0):

I just received my 14" with M1 Max and quickly tested League of Legends.
I tried different settings, **Window mode: Borderless** seems to be working best together with **Wait for vertical sync: Disabled** but it's still not 100% fluid.

I have a 34" LG ultrawide connected via TB3.

My previous setup was a 15" MBP i9 with eGPU via TB 3 (RX Vega 64) connected via DisplayPort and the game was 100% fluid even in full screen mode.

I have a feeling there is something weird going on with the TB3 connection.
I will try to connect the monitor via HDMI to see if that makes it better.

Would be curious to see if there are other people experiencing this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Out of curiosity, what settings are you running the game at? I would assume the M1 Max can handle everything at the highest level, but I wanted to be sure. 
Also, are the fluidity issues related to display glitchiness like what I described, or more standard frame drops/lower framerate?

Comment: Today I tested also with the HDMI cable directly connected and no difference. 
I'm running the game at very high max settings, it's super fluid and no frame drops/stuttering on internal monitor, even with v-sync activated.
On the external monitor 3440x1440 unfortunately I tried every setting but still does a bit of stuttering :(

Comment: Ah that sucks :( LoL runs non-natively, so maybe it is an unfortunate reality that it might not run 100% smoothly at max settings on a 1440p ultrawide display.
Does the stuttering stop if you reduce the quality to High for instance?

Comment: That's something I need to test but on the internal monitor works flawlessly with ~100FPS at max details with 2048x1200 I think to remember so not far away from the external monitor resolution, but I'll give it a try ! :D

Comment: @KarimNassar out of curiosity with your 4k display what level of detail are you using and what FPS do you see?

Comment: Ahah agree! Careful though, for your ultrawide external monitor, your MBP has to drive twice the raw number of pixels, so it might not be shocking that you see a drop in performance unrelated to I/O weirdness that might be occurring ^^
I run everything on high at a 1080p in-game scaled resolution, and get a solid 120-145 FPS.

Comment: I tested yesterday decreasing the detail level but no changes. I also paid extra attention when there are these micro lag / stuttering the FPS counter doesn't move from 60fps so it's definitely not a problem with the GPU "raw power" but rather some software glitch imho.